# Meteor MongoDB update RangeError

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor

just going trough the Meteor tutorial and wanted to introduce methods for add, update and remove functions, so that i am not writing directly from client with giving the permission to do it with Collection.allow... Doing it with methods, I am always running into

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.toString (native)
    at isArguments (http://localhost:3000/packages/es5-shim.js?03b82f907286b5353e3a371eb320635a634fc88b:988:12)
    at Function.keys (http://localhost:3000/packages/es5-shim.js?03b82f907286b5353e3a371eb320635a634fc88b:1051:13)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?46eaedbdeb6e71c82af1b16f51c7da4127d6f285:155:20)
    at Object.EJSON.clone (http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?5e95dd4b5971d96cb2d3287c54b14d9002f83ab7:528:5)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?5e95dd4b5971d96cb2d3287c54b14d9002f83ab7:529:22
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?46eaedbdeb6e71c82af1b16f51c7da4127d6f285:157:22)
    at Object.EJSON.clone (http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?5e95dd4b5971d96cb2d3287c54b14d9002f83ab7:528:5)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?5e95dd4b5971d96cb2d3287c54b14d9002f83ab7:529:22
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?46eaedbdeb6e71c82af1b16f51c7da4127d6f285:157:22)
```

So this is my code:

*Methods*:

```
Meteor.methods({
  addParty: function (party) {
    // Make sure the user is logged in before inserting a task
    if (!Meteor.userId()) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('not-authenticated');
    }

    party.owner = Meteor.userId();
    party.username = Meteor.user().username;
    party.createdAt = new Date();

    Parties.insert(party);
  },
  removeParty: function (party) {
    // Make sure only the party owner can delete a party
    if (party.owner !== Meteor.userId()) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
    }
    Parties.remove(party._id);
  },
  updateParty: function (party) {
    // Make sure only the party owner can delete a party
    if (party.owner !== Meteor.userId()) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
    }
    Parties.update(party._id, party);
  }
});
```

UI:
Here you will see and change the details of the party:

```
<input ng-model="party.name">
<input ng-model="party.description">
<label>Is public</label>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="party.public">

<button ng-click="save(party)">Save</button>
<button ng-click="reset()">Reset form</button>
<button ui-sref="parties">Cancel</button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.party = $meteor.object(Parties, $stateParams.partyId, false);

$scope.save = function(updatedParty) {
  $meteor.call('updateParty', updatedParty);
};
```

but this is working when doing on a collection:

```
$scope.addParty = function(newParty){
    $meteor.call('addParty', newParty);
  }

  $scope.remove = function(party){
     $meteor.call('removeParty', party);
  }
```

And when I do it like it is in the tutorial, calling it from the client, it works, but i want to have it as a method and update all fields in this document. I also tried to remove in the Meteor.methods.updateParty all content, or with $set, still getting the error. Nothing seems to work what i try. Does somebody sees where the problem is?

Thank you

**Update 29.10.2015. 17:51**

Ok, when i change the receiving of the party from:

```
 $scope.party = $meteor.object(Parties, $stateParams.partyId, false).subscribe('parties');
```

to:

```
$scope.party = Parties.findOne($stateParams.partyId);
```

then the method call works. But what does not work now is when i update the page, the party is not fetched again, just when I am coming the first time. Any hints to that?

The question is now, which is the right way to do it.

Should i fetch it with Parties.findOne... or is it fine to fetch it with $meteor.object and define that i can write from the client with Parties Allow:

```
Parties.allow({
  update: function (userId, party, fields, modifier) {
    return userId && party.owner === userId;
  }
});
```

Comment: Not sure since I don't use angular but I think there's an infinite loop that crash the stack. it can happen with double binding system like angular.

Comment: @acemtp, thanks for your comment. Ok, what kind of infinite loop? I updated it, when i use $meteor.object.. with Parties.Allow, then it works, but then i am writing from the client to DB, not sure if this is the correct way of doing it.. but in the tutorial is this one used..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have a working solution.

I created a method in the model (shared code between client and server) to retrieve one party from DB:

```
getOneParty: function(partyId) {
    var party = Parties.findOne(partyId);
    return party;
  },
```

then in the client i have this:

```
$meteor.subscribe('parties');
$scope.partyId = $stateParams.partyId; // getting this data from params
$party = $meteor.call('getOneParty', $scope.getReactively('partyId')).then(
      function(data){
        $scope.party = data;
        console.log('successfully got Party: ', data);
      },
      function(err){
        console.log('failed', err);
      }
    );
```

then I am able to call this function without any problems from the UI:

```
$scope.save = function(updatedParty) {
       $meteor.call('updateParty', updatedParty);
    };
```

So, still not sure if the other way below is the better, but at least I have now two version working :) Not sure regarding the below one, since the Client is then writing directly to DB, which is not so secure?

Client Code:

```
$meteor.subscribe('parties');
$scope.party = $meteor.object(Parties, $stateParams.partyId, false);
```

Update Method:

```
$scope.save = function(updatedParty) {
       $scope.party.save().then(function(numberOfDocs){
         console.log('save success doc affected ', numberOfDocs);
       }, function(error){
         console.log('save error', error);
       });
    };
```

but for that, it is necessary to give permission to the client to do that. You can do that in the model:

```
Parties.allow({
  update: function (userId, party, fields, modifier) {
    return userId && party.owner === userId;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $scope.$meteorSubscribe('parties', $stateParams.partyId).then(function() {
        $scope.party= s.$meteorObject(Parties, {
            _id: $stateParams.partyId
        }, false);
    }, function(data) {
        alert("Error loading ");
        console.log(data);
    })
```

I had the same problem doing it your way, don't really know why. For some reason this fixed it for me.